# Looking to remove "[]" and " ' ' " from a panda's output in python

Tags: python, pandas

Ive been stuck trying to figure out how to remove unwanted things from my output. What im trying to do is parse data from an excel sheet and store it in an array to be called later when using '''pygui.typewrite()'''. My code looks like this

```
## OPENING FILES ##
# Opens the path to the prints 
entries = Path(r'C:\Users\jmcintosh\LIDT Project (copy)\LIDT 
Project\Solidworks Test (DEV)')
# Opens excel sheet for reading 
xlEntries = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jmcintosh\LIDT Project 
(copy)\LIDT Project\LIDT New Webspec Titles 2.0.xlsx')



partNumbers = [] # Make partNumbers the array for partnumbers, 
gathers the names as well as the partnumbers 



# For loop that allow iteration through the directory of names.
for entry in entries.iterdir():
    partNumbertemp = re.findall('[0-9]+', entry.name)
    partNumbers.append(int(partNumbertemp[0]))    
# Appends the array with the regex function to parse only the 
integers of the file name to be used later.

# While loop to remove blank file names from directory issues
while ([] in partNumbers):
    partNumbers.remove([])

rowNumber= []
specName= []
specValue= []
rowNumbertemp = []
specNametemp =[]
specValuetemp =[]

k = 0
while (k<fileCount):

#uses partnumbers to check if the index of the array is in the column
rowNumbertemp.append(xlEntries.loc[xlEntries['StockNumber'] == partNumbers[k]].index.to_numpy())  
rowNumber.append(rowNumbertemp[k])

# in the same row it grabs the specific cell value from anoother column
specNametemp = (xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"Pat's Proposed Change"].tolist())
specName.append(str(specNametemp))

# in the same row it grabs the specific cell value from anoother column
specValuetemp = (xlEntries.loc[rowNumber[k],"StringValue"].tolist())   
specValue.append(str(specValuetemp))

k = k + 1
print(specValue)
print(specName)
```

My output prints like this :
`["['7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['10 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 532nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', "['15 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 1064nm, 20ns, 20Hz']", "['7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz']"] ["['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, by design']", '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[]', "['damage threshold, certified']", "['damage threshold, certified']"]`

I need it to look like this :

`damage threshold, certified,damage threshold, certified, damage threshold, certified`
`7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz, 7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz, 7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz,7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz,7.5 J/cm<sup>2</sup> @ 355nm, 20ns, 20Hz ,`

Ive tried `.remove()` , `split()` , and tried . `tolist()`, `listoflists` , and `str.join`.
Im really at a loss and need some help.any would be appreciated!! I just need the brackets and quotes gone so i can use it to type write onto a drawing.

The excel sheet looks like this

[image: This is a snippet of the sheet. You can see the columns im pulling from as well.]

Comment: There is no print statement in your code, nor DataFrame creation. How do you get this output? Can you show your complete code, and (a subset of) the contents of the excel file? This guide might help you complete your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sure one moment

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to remove all the squire brackets. You can do it like this.
Assuming you have your data in a list.

```
mylist = []  # The data you got from excel. with all []
newlist = []  # created from the excel data.
for x in mylist:  # loop through your list
    if x != '[]':  # ignore the empty []
        # extract substring from index 2 to index -2 add to newlist
        newlist.append(x[2:-2])
```

You can also use list comprehension.

```
newlist = [x[2:-2] for x in mylist if x != '[]']
```

Comment: im not sure if this is what im looking to do. Yes i want to remove them but i need to remove it from my output. Printing is just me chekcing to see if its correct.  Ideally i want my output to look like the second output so i can have python type it into a file for me without all the extra formatting.

Comment: I updated the answer. See, after reading from excel, you have a list with squire brackets. You can create a new list after removing the brackets. and use this new one later in your code.

Comment: Ive tried this and it essentially deletes the output of specName. Thank you for ur help thus far but this does not fix the problem. I appreciate the assistance

Comment: I am unsure how you managed to do that. It should be impossible to delete the output by following what I said. Anyway, i tried.

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to look like this

In order to get the desired output, extracting data from your pandas DataFrame row by row in a while loop is an unneeded complication. You can get your data in a list more directly with the code below (notice I did some cleanup before loading the dataframe using `skiprows` argument from `read_file`).

```py
xl_entries = pd.read_excel("your file", skiprows=1)
spec_name = xl_entries["NewSpecificationName"].to_list()
spec_value = xl_entries["StringValue"].to_list()
print(spec_name)
print(spec_value)
```

This should answer your question of removing "[]" and "''" from the output.

But I understand that your final goal is not to print your data neatly:

> What im trying to do is parse data from an excel sheet and store it in an array to be called later

Again I would advise not to extract your DataFrame's contents into an array using while loops, but directly call the contents of your DataFrame using [panda's rich indexing functionalities](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data).